# Flatscreen refresh rate fault?

Tags: drivers, display

The screen of a user on my network is weird. Like a too low refresh rate, you can see "refresh lines" going accross the screen. Best thing I've done so far is narrow it down to being "not related" to the screen. I swapped it for another one and tried: Same problem.

I boosted the refresh rate to 75hz, which seemed to help a LITTLE bit at first, but killed the screen soon afterwards.

I checked if the graphic card was well inserted into its slot, and if the drivers for it were up to date, both look alright, although I had to correct the card's position, as it was not properly screwed in place.

What should I try next? Changing the graphic card for something else? Like a muffin or a leprechaun?

**Updated details**
As for the details:

OS: Win XP 64
Display Adapter: Radeon x700
Drivers: Updated today
Display: Not faulty, tried other ones.
Plugged on VGA

Comment: Give the superuser beta a try, this is a perfect SU question.  ewok.adventure is the password.

Comment: Question is totally lacking in details:

* What OS?
* What monitor?
* What gfx card?
* What drivers?

Comment: +1 for asking the details. Knowing what monitor it is could help in researching for the recommended refresh rate, aside from the other helpful advice presented here.

Comment: Also, what interface are you using to connect the video card and monitor?  DVI?  VGA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next logical step would be to try a different graphics card.

It sounds to me like it is the most likely source of the problem as the monitor has been ruled out.

It could just be a dud card, it could be overheating, or it could have overheated at some point in the past and done itself an injury.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try booting the machine from a live ubuntu CD/USB or similar, see if it's an OS/driver or video card thing.

Comment: I already know it's not the driver, even during the bios part of booting, it's doing the flicker stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yout might want to check your monitor cable and move it around a bit to make sure it is not interference from something.  Are you using analog (VGA) or digital (DVI) monitor connections?

After this has been checked, might want to look into trying a different video card to see if that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

Change the power cable, then try plugging it in to a different circuit.